# Is there a blogging platform supporting AMP?

Tags: amp-html

I would need a simple website. I would prefer to use one of the cheap or free services to build and host it, but this being 2017, I'd love to see it use [AMP](https://www.ampproject.org). Is there a service that generates AMP for the site they build for you?

Simple googling did not lead me far on  this, so a quick tip from the AMP community would be welcome here.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a webserver with node.js installed and have privileges to manage the server, try out [ghost](https://ghost.org/de/).

It is based on node.js and its main focus is on blogging, so you do not have any kind of static pages like wordpress does, but I personally prefer it if you just want to publish blog posts with all features that matter for this reason.

And don't wonder about the Pricing tab, this is only if you want them to host your blog. If you host it on your own, then it's free ...

Comment: Thanks. ghost looks nice, but overkill for a simple site, e.g. for an academic with an occasional update. Managing a server is too much, or paying $19 a month is too much. Or maybe that'll change with 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

Check CMS section of below link
https://www.ampproject.org/support/faqs/supported-platforms